# MySQL searching using many 'like' operators: is there a better way?

Tags: mysql, search, html-table, sql-like

I have a page that gets all rows from a table in a database, then displays the rows in an HTML table.
That works great, but now I want to implement a 'search' feature. There is a searchbox, and search-terms are separated by a space. I am going to make it search three fields for the search terms, 'make' 'model' and 'type.' These three fields are VARCHAR(30).

Currently if I wanted to search using 3 terms (say 'cool' 'abc' and '123') my query would look something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE make LIKE '%cool%' OR make LIKE '%abc%' OR make LIKE '%123%' OR model LIKE '%cool%' OR model LIKE '%abc%' OR model LIKE '%123%' OR type LIKE '%cool%' OR type LIKE '%abc%' OR type LIKE '%123%'
```

That looks *really* bad, and it will get even worse if there are more search terms or more fields to search.
My question to you: is there a better way to search? If so, what?

Comment: Make notice, that this query does full table scan and it will be slow on big tables.

Comment: Does thecodeeveloper's do that too? Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: Yes, REGEXP does full scan too.

Comment: You might like to read my presentation https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use REGEXP instead of like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE make REGEXP 'cool|abc|123' OR model REGEXP 'cool|abc|123' OR type REGEXP 'cool|abc|123';
```

read more about REGEXP

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2337

Answer (score 2):

You should use FULLTEXT. Search SO about it, it is very easy and useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JQuery Table Plugin, like [data tables](http://www.datatables.net) Features on-the-fly filtering which you could use instead of a lengthy sql command. And its free.

Comment: Wow, that has all the features I was planning on creating myself!

Comment: Yeah its quality! Hope i answered your question.

Comment: i think it may be a bit much though. Thanks for the cool info anyway.